# Unable to find module 'mscorwks.dll'

Tags: .net, windows, windbg

I try to use the winDBG to debug a dump file. When I run .loadby sos mscorwks.dll

It gave me an error message. 
Unable to find module 'mscorwks.dll'

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't add the .dll, try just `.loadby sos mscorwks`

Comment: This still gives error message  Unable to find module 'mscorwks.dll' for me

Comment: This still gives error message Unable to find module 'mscorwks.dll' for me

Answer (score 122):

If you are debugging a **.NET 4.0** application, you need to use the following instead of `mscorwks`:

`.loadby sos clr`

[Here is a good overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-managed-code) of the commands available for different versions of the *FULL* .NET framework.  Enjoy!!

Answer (score 19):

I had this issue as well and it turned out to be because the debugger was breaking into the app before the CLR was loaded. I had to let the app run throug further before I could do much of anything.

Doing this in windbg might help:

```
sxe ld:mscorlib
g
(... breaks again ...)
.loadby sos mscorwks
```

The 'sxe ld:..' stops on module load.

As Sixto mentions, if you are debugging dotnet 4 apps you'll need to replace the last line with

```
.loadby sos clr
```

Comment: Yes, this was my problem. It broke too early. I didn't have to load mscorlib myself, I just let the application go a bit further (until it hit `Console.ReadLine()`, by writing `g` before `.loadby sos mscorwks`.

Answer (score 3):

Also ensure you have correct bitness - trying to do this in 64-bit windbg while debugging 32-bit app will give you the same error.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the .NET framework directory (e.g. c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727) in your path, you can just use

```
.load sos
```